# How can I set spring profile on tomcat7-maven-plugin?

Tags: spring, maven-tomcat-plugin

How can I set active spring profile o tomcat maven plugin? I want to get active profiles in runtime from Environment, but I' always getting empty array.

I tried to add this systemProperties in plugin configuration in pom.xml:

```
<JAVA_OPTS>-Dspring.profiles.active=local</JAVA_OPTS>
```

or

```
<name>spring.profiles.active</name>
<value>locale</value>
```

I try to add this in context.xml:

```
<environment name="spring.profiles.active" value="local" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

But still getting no active profile...

My env: Java 6, tomcat7-maven-plugin version 2.2, Netbeans 8.0.2, Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.

My pom.xml tomcat plugin looks this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>

    <configuration>
        <!-- http port -->
        <port>8084</port>
        <contextFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources-local/context.xml</contextFile>
        <systemProperties>
            <JAVA_OPTS>-Dspring.profiles.active=local</JAVA_OPTS>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>tomcat-run</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run-war</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
<dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tomcat 7 Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) shows a different syntax for System Properties like the one below. So try doing it this way:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<configuration>
  <systemProperties>
    <example.value.1>alpha</example.value.1>
    <example.value.2>beta</example.value.2>
  </systemProperties>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This way I can read "local" value using System.getProperty("spring.profile.active"), but environment.getActiveProfiles() still returning empty array... It is partial solution, maybe it would be enough for my purpose... Thanks

Comment: @CodeRunner, your edits were incorrect. You have to revert it. You updated it with tomcat6 info whereas the question is about tomcat7. I would rejected the edit, but didn't get chance. I don't option to reject the edit now.

Comment: @minion I have corrected it. Thanks for pointing out the version error - the rest of my edits were correct and in line with the tomcat7 docu.